# Objective-C code has property called "extension" which is keyword in Swift. How to set that property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, smartfoxserver

I am using SmartFoxServer iOS client API.

There is this property I need to set from Objective-C

```
@property (strong) RoomExtension *extension;
```

Unfortunately extension is keyword in Swift. I am trying to find some workaround to set the property as there is no constructor working with it.

Any suggestions will be great. I can, of course, move the whole thing to Objective-C side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the documentation [Naming Constants and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_455), you can surround the name with the backtick character. For example:

```
let `extension` = "something"
```